# Is there a good way to shorten these if/elif/else statements?

Tags: python-3.x

I am an amateur when it comes to programming and understanding the concepts, so I wanted to know whether or not I could shorten this code down. I have heard about the phrase "spaghetti code" before, and I am trying my best not to fall down that path of bad, messy code.
Here's my code:

```
if amount[-1] == 's' and amount[:-1].isnumeric():
    amount = int(amount[:-1])
    unit = "seconds"
elif amount[-1] == 'm' and amount[:-1].isnumeric():
    amount = int(amount[:-1])*60
    unit = "minutes"
elif amount[-2:] == 'hr' and amount[:-2].isnumeric():
    amount = int(amount[:-1])*60*60
    unit = "hours"
elif amount[-1] == 'd' and amount[:-1].isnumeric():
    amount = int(amount[:-1])*60*60*24
    unit = "days"
elif reason != None:
    reason = f'{amount} {reason}'
else:
    reason = f'{amount}'
```

The user inputs an amount of time (ex: 6hr, 34m, 2s, or 1d) and is used later in the program. Is there a good way to trim this down?

Comment: create a dictionary that has `dx = {'s':'seconds','m':'minutes','hr':'hours','d':'days'}` Then you can do `unit = dx[amount[01]]` Also you can check if `amount[-1] in dx.keys()`, then you can do the other two commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've all been there, I believe one good way to get better at this would be first to analyze the problem and find a pattern in the data your program expects. One pattern that's noticeable is:

- The user always inputs a string (because "22hr, 2m, 4d" are alpha-numeric values)
- A valid input would always have numbers and alphabets (hr, m, s, d) in it
- A valid input would always start with a number

These are some of the patterns you can bring out from the problem. Now for the solution:

- validate your input starts with a number ( you can make other validations at the top)

```py
if amount[0].isnumeric():
  # remaining logic here
```

This eliminates the need to keep repeating yourself on every `elif`

- Next, set a list of dictionaries of allowed alphabetical characters, their unit and their numerical value

```py
timeOptions = [
   { 'shortcode': 'm', 'unit': 'minutes', 'value': 60 },
   { 'shortcode': 's', 'unit': 'seconds', 'value': 1 },
   { 'shortcode': 'hr', 'unit': 'hours', 'value': 3600 },
   { 'shortcode': 'd', 'unit': 'days', 'value': 86400 },
]
```

- Next filter the numerical values from the string

```py
number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, amount))
```

- Filter the alphabet values from the string

```py
shortcode = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, amount))
```

Finally from your dictionary, find the dictionary entry whose shortcode property matches the unit from the user's input. For this, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
timeValue = [x for x in li if x["shortcode"] == shortcode ][0] # refactor to check list length before attempting to access the first item
```

finally, you can do whatever you want with the user's input and the `timeValue` dictionary.

```
amount = amount * timeValue["value"]
unit = timeValue["unit"]
```

The entire program might look like this:

```py
if amount[0].isnumeric():
    timeOptions = [
      { 'shortcode': 'm', 'unit': 'minutes', 'value': 60 },
      { 'shortcode': 's', 'unit': 'seconds', 'value': 1 },
      { 'shortcode': 'hr', 'unit': 'hours', 'value': 3600 },
      { 'shortcode': 'd', 'unit': 'days', 'value': 86400 },
    ]
    number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, amount))
    shortcode = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, amount))

    timeValue = [x for x in li if x["shortcode"] == shortcode ]

    if len(timeValue):
      return False
    else:
      timeValue = timeValue[0]

    amount = amount * timeValue["value"]
    unit = timeValue["unit"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lookup problem, so it's best to treat it like one. I'm not quite sure what unit is being used for so I left it in, though the function could be simplified if only the number of seconds is required.

In terms of "trimming the code down", stability and readability are often the most important factors. Therefore, the larger benefit is gained from separating this logic into a separate function.

```
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ParseResult:
    seconds:int
    original_unit:str

TIME_UNITS = {
    's': ('seconds',1),
    'm': ('minutes',60),
    'hr': ('hours',60*60),
    'd': ('days',60*60*24)
}

def parse_time(text):
    # match digits and then not digits
    match = re.match(r'(\d+)(\D+)',text)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid input format for "{text}"')
    amount,unit = match.groups()
    if unit not in TIME_UNITS:
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid unit "{unit}"')
    unit_name, seconds_per_unit = TIME_UNITS[unit]
    seconds = seconds_per_unit * int(amount)
    return ParseResult(seconds,unit_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Observations from your code:
You have `amount` as a string. Inside your if statement, you are changing it to an integer. You should consider using another variable to store the value.

Also, for the conditions, you can use a dictionary and store the patterns. Then look up the key and use the values for computing.

I have used a for loop with multiple examples to test the code. Results are also shared.

Here's a modified code that is reduced a bit.

```
for amount in ['20s','20m','20hr','20d','20r','20a','20','abc','as','ad','ahr','am']:

    #setup code to initialize some key variables

    amt, unit = 0, ''
    if amount == '20r': reason = None
    else: reason = ''

    #logic for your part of the code

    dx = {'s':('seconds',1),'m':('minutes',60),'d':('days',60*60*24),'hr':('hours',3600)}

    if amount[-1] in dx.keys() and amount[:-1].isnumeric():
        unit = dx[amount[-1]][0]
        amt = int(amount[:-1])* dx[amount[-1]][1]
    elif amount[-2:] in dx.keys() and amount[:-1].isnumeric():
        unit = dx[amount[-2:]][0]
        amt = int(amount[:-2])* dx[amount[-2:]][1]
    elif reason != None:
        reason = f'{amount} {reason}'
    else:
        reason = f'{amount}'

    #logic for your code ends here

    #The rest is to print the results of the logic from above

    print ('amount :',amount, ',amt :',amt, ',unit :',unit, ',reason :',reason)
```

Output from this code are:

```
amount : 20s ,amt : 20 ,unit : seconds ,reason : 
amount : 20m ,amt : 1200 ,unit : minutes ,reason : 
amount : 20hr ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : 20hr 
amount : 20d ,amt : 1728000 ,unit : days ,reason : 
amount : 20r ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : 20r
amount : 20a ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : 20a 
amount : 20 ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : 20 
amount : abc ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : abc 
amount : as ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : as 
amount : ad ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : ad 
amount : ahr ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : ahr 
amount : am ,amt : 0 ,unit :  ,reason : am
```